# Is this Topology Proof Rigorous?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, alternative-proof

**Question:**
On the three-point set X = {a, b, c}, the trivial topology has two open sets and the discrete topology has eight open sets. For each of n = 3,...,7, either find a topology on X consisting of n open sets or prove that no such topology exists.

*I was able to find a topology for each n except n = 7. So I tried to prove that the topology does not exist this way:*

We prove this by contradiction. Suppose n(T) = 7 exists for a three-point set X, then the elements of T will either be:
(i) the empty set, X, two singleton sets and three sets each of two elements or
(ii) the empty set, X, three singleton sets and two sets each of two elements

**case(i):** this is impossible since the intersection of elements of T will not always be closed (there exist a pair of sets each of two elements whose intersection is a singleton set not in T)

**case(ii):** this is impossible since the union of two singleton sets is not always closed (there exist a pair of singleton sets whose union will give a set with two elements not found in T).

Since we have shown that both possibilities of the elements of T do not exist, then n(T) = 7 is not a topology for a three-point set X and this concludes the proof.

**Note:** I feel this proof is not rigorous. I will welcome contributions from you guys. I will also like to see alternative proof. Thanks

Comment: This looks good, except when you say "closed" do you really mean "open"?

Comment: This isn’t a proof until you show that your two cases are the *only* two cases you can have when $n=7$. In other words, you need to explain why your cases *exhaust* all the possibilities. (It is not hard to do so, but if I were grading this, and there were no such explanation, I would deduct points.) All you’ve done so far is say, this kind of seven-element topology doesn’t exist, and this kind doesn’t either. The devil’s advocate wonders, what if there’s another kind?

Comment: @symplectomorphic If I were grading this, I would not deduct points (except for saying "closed" when it should read "open"). I would have put it a different way, but the way the OP put it is also good to me. I would have said, if n(T)=7, then there is only one set that is not open. Since X and the empty set are open, this one set must be either (i) a singleton, or (ii) a two-point set. If say the singleton {a} is not open, a contradiction since it is the intersection of the open sets {a,b} and {a,c}. For (ii) if say {a,b} were not open, contradiction, since it is the union of open {a} and {b}.

Comment: By 'closed', I mean the closure property is satisfied. If there is any other way I could have said that, I will be happy to know

Comment: @Mirko I think that helps a lot and settles everything for me. Thanks

Comment: I guess I should have focused on whether a set is 'open' or 'close' rather than whether the closure property is satisfied. Thanks

Comment: @symplectomorphic I will really appreciate it if you can just briefly show me how I can show my cases exhaust all possibilities, if you don't mind.

Comment: @Mirko: then you aren’t a very good grader, or at least you aren’t teaching the student what they need to do to give a complete proof. What you wrote in your comment isn’t a “different way” of putting it; it’s a different point entirely, which makes explicit that the cases the OP considers are in fact exhaustive. The OP’s proof doesn’t make that argument at all.

Comment: @MrProf I see what you meant by T not being closed (I think) it is not closed under the operation of taking unions of open sets, or the operation of taking intersection of finitely many open sets. Regarding comments (between symplectomorphic and myself) as to how one would/should be grading this, I am divided... to me the sentence "there exist a pair of sets each of two elements whose intersection is a singleton set not in T" sounds like enough of a justification to obtain the conclusion ... but perhaps you need to provide justification, or details, why this sentence is true.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\tau$ is a topology on $X=\{1,2,3\}$ such that $|\tau|=7$, which means there is a *unique* set $A \subseteq X$ such that $A \notin \tau$, as $X$ has indeed exactly $8$ subsets.

$|A| = 0$ is impossible as then $A=\emptyset$ and $\emptyset \in \tau$ by one of the topology axioms.

$|A|=3$ is also impossible as then $A=X$ and $X \in \tau$ by axiom.

If $|A|=1$ we have $A=\{i\}$ for some $ i \in X$ but then let $j,k$ be the two other elements of $X$. We must have $\{i,j\}, \{i,k\} \in \tau$ as $A$ was the unique subset not in $\tau$ and so these must be in $\tau$. But then $\{i,j\}\cap \{i,k\} = \{i\} \in \tau$ too, as a finite intersection of members of $\tau$. This is a contradiction.

The final case is $|A|=2$ so $A= \{i,j\}$ for $i,j \in X$. But again we must have that $\{i\},\{j\} \in \tau$ (other subsets are in $\tau$) and then $\{i\} \cup \{j\}=A \in \tau$ (closedness under unions), contradiction. So all cases lead to contradictions and we've shown the impossibility of $|\tau|=7$.

Comment: I really appreciate your post. Thanks